# Are there inference rules for introducing and elimination implication `->` in the antecedent (the part on the left of `|-`)?

Tags: logic

Deductive theorem says that `P, Q |- S`, if and only if `P |- (Q->S)`.
I found that the deductive theorem is inference rules for introducing and elimination implication `->` in the succedent (the part on the right of `|-`).

Are there inference rules for introducing and elimination implication `->` in the antecedent (the part on the left of `|-`)?

- Introduction: If `... |- ...`, where `...` on the left hand side doesn't include implication, then `..., (Q->S) |- ...`.
- Elimination: If `..., (Q->S) |- ...`, then `... |- ...`, where `...` on the left hand side doesn't include implication.

Thanks.